# Unity GUI not working with Tango

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I wanted to create a quick "main menu" scene for my [Google Tango](https://www.google.com/atap/project-tango/) project using [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).
This is the code I got:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour {

    public Object[] scenes;

    void OnGUI () {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 200, 200, 100), "test Button")){}

        for (int i = 0; i < scenes.Length; i++) {
            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0, i * Screen.height / scenes.Length, Screen.width, Screen.height / scenes.Length), "Load " + scenes[i].name)){
                Application.LoadLevel(scenes[i].name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should (and does.. at least in the Editor) work just fine.
However I can only see the single "test Button" on screen.

Why does this happen?

Comment: RUB3N, I just tested your code with an empty project, it works. Could you double check to see if there's anything else blocking the GUI?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code. How many scene you included in the build?

Comment: It's seven scenes. But I don't really get it, since it works in the Editor and the "test Button" also works on the device.

Comment: hi RUB3N, could you see if it work on any other android device? I can see a potential problem caused by how unity package the scene list. Maybe if you run on desktop, the scene list is packaged no matter if you check them in the build settting?